# OpenLdap "Server is unwilling to perform (53) additional info: no global superior knowledge"

Tags: openldap

I am new in `Ldap`, and I can't understand why is giving me that error, when I try to import that file.
   I've tried this command:

```
ldapadd -h elara.alu.com -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=alu,dc=com" -f /root/usersFromDavid.ldif
```

And my `olcDatabase={2}bdb.ldif`  look like this:

```
#CRC32 dd2c457a
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcBdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}bdb
olcSuffix: dc=alu,dc=com
olcAddContentAcl: FALSE
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcMaxDerefDepth: 15
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=alu,dc=com
olcSyncUseSubentry: FALSE
olcMonitoring: TRUE
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcDbCacheSize: 1000
olcDbCheckpoint: 1024 15
olcDbNoSync: FALSE
olcDbDirtyRead: FALSE
olcDbIDLcacheSize: 0
olcDbIndex: objectClass pres,eq
olcDbIndex: cn pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: uid pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: uidNumber pres,eq
olcDbIndex: gidNumber pres,eq
olcDbIndex: ou pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: mail pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: sn pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: givenName pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: memberUid pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: loginShell pres,eq
olcDbIndex: nisMapName pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: nisMapEntry pres,eq,sub
olcDbLinearIndex: FALSE
olcDbMode: 0600
olcDbSearchStack: 16
olcDbShmKey: 0
olcDbCacheFree: 1
olcDbDNcacheSize: 0
structuralObjectClass: olcBdbConfig
entryUUID: 7f7892aa-66a8-1034-968b-61cac64128b9
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150324193414Z
entryCSN: 20150324193414.304614Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150324193414Z
olcRootPW: {SSHA}Ih6JIB2w69nqoZksZsa46ORHNnHBKNbI
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.pem
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/examplekey.pem
```

I tried to add:

```
dn: o=users

objectclass: extensibleObject

objectclass: top

objectclass: domain

dc: users

o: users



dn: ou=People,o=users,cn=Manager, dc=alu, dc=com

objectclass: top

objectclass: organizationalunit

ou: People



dn: uid=caterinca,ou=People,o=users,cn=Manager, dc=alu, dc=com

objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
cn: Caterinca
sn: Caterinca
description: enabled
mail: caterinca@caterinca
title: admin
uid: caterinca
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9Nk0vd2tUY3JSdEpiZUZWU2RzYWszbjhlVWV2eEk4aitCb3psNGc9P
```

Comment: Entier error: adding new entry "o=users"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
 additional info: no global superior knowledge